# Try Send Smtp in godaddy

Tags: smtp, godaddy-api

I'm trying to send mail from my MVC application which is working fine in my local machine. It works well in local, but when I publish it in godaddy, it didn't send any emails and I didn't get any error.

Here is the code. I'm using MVC .net framework

```
  // Attach the file path to the email (if an attachment was saved)
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilePath))
  {
      mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentFilePath));
  }

  using (var smtp = new SmtpClient
  {
      Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net",
      Port = 25,
      EnableSsl = false,
      UseDefaultCredentials = false,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MailAddress", "Password")
  })
  {
      smtp.Send(mm);
```